# Is there a way to install Benq pointwrite on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, wine

I've tried installing the software PointWrite_PW21U_Pen_Win (2.4.1.1) (https://business-display.benq.com/en/findproduct/projector/accessory/pointwrite-pw21u/download.html) on Ubuntu 16.04 with wine.

This software provides drivers to run an interactive pen on a board. The pen can then be used like a mouse to write on a whiteboard.

Here's a detailed description of the installation process: The installation starts as it does in Windows and doesn't show any error messages during the whole process. In Windows, however, a cmd-window pops up during the installation, which obviously doesn't happen during the wine installation in Ubuntu.

After starting the program in Ubuntu, I get the error message "The driver did not install correctly".

[image: error message]

An icon of the program appears at the menu bar, where "configuration", "calibration" etc. are greyed out.

[image: icon at the menu bar]

Are there other possibilities to get the pens running apart from wine? At my school, we have installed Ubuntu on all computers and I don't really want to switch to Windows, because I prefer the policy of Linux (open source...) and there are about 200 programs installed on our Ubuntu system that would have to be newly installed in Windows.

As a workaround, I've installed Win 7 on a computer, the pen drivers and then installed our Ubuntu system in a virtual box. However, it's pretty slow (old computers...) and not very stable.

Any way to get these Benq pens running in Ubuntu would be fantastic for us!

Comment: In general, drivers made for Windows should not work through Wine. If you can't find a Linux driver you may be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link! I tried to install the package provided there, but the installation of the Pointwrite.deb package didn't work properly - I guess because it is only developed for Ubuntu 14.04. However, I have contacted the Benq Asia support, maybe they can help me a bit more than the Europeans - they didn't even know that there are Linux drivers at all...

Comment: Now I got an answer from Benq: all they say is that currently they don't support Linux - wow... - I still hope to get some help here...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install the Linux drivers package from http://benq.ph/product/accessory/pw02/downloads - which was developed for an earlier version of our pens an for Ubuntu 14.04. My installation on Ubuntu 16.04 didn't work, although I followed exactly the instruction sheet given in the drivers package.

Here's a screenshot that shows the installation process of the pointwrite deb package in the terminal - the installation of the qwrite package worked as described in the instruction sheet without any errors:

[installation process of the Pointwrite drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x61pp.png)

Another screenshot shows the error message I'm getting when starting the QWrite software:

[error message after starting qwrite software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFkDv.png)

May it be that it's a problem with the newer Ubuntu version?

Thanks a lot for your help!